# Как присвоить CSS к блоку?

Tags: javascript

На странице есть несколько блоков с такой разметкой, изменяется только `id="full?"`

```
<div class="boxx">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="item stat-panel text-center dub-block">
            <header>
                <h2 class="name-track-short">
                    <div class="play_listfull">
                        <a id="full5640" class="playfull viewsfull" href="#">Crossfaith - Revolution</a>
                    </div>
                </h2> 
            </header>   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Как можно присвоить к классу `boxx` стиль `display:none`, если в ссылке `a` присутствует класс `viewsfull`

Comment: Только посредством Javascript ? или можно использовать jQuery ?

Comment: Разве что через js  - легко. Нельзя сослаться на родительские элементы через css. Даже на предыдущие сестренские нельзя.

Comment: Без разницы, js или jquery

Comment: Советую класс `viewsfull` присуждать элементу `.boxx`, который хотите скрыть, и описать для него свой `display:none`, но я хз какая у тебя структура, так что это такое.

Comment: Структуру менять нельзя

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('.boxx').each(function(){
   if($(this).find('a').hasClass('viewsfull')){
   $(this).hide()
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="boxx">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="item stat-panel text-center dub-block">
            <header>
                <h2 class="name-track-short">
                    <div class="play_listfull">
                        <a id="full5640" class="playfull viewsfull" href="#">Crossfaith - Revolution</a>
                    </div>
                </h2> 
            </header>   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Pavel Mayorov [указал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/623482/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0/623524?noredirect=1#comment869637_623524) на то, что проще использовать селектор :has, чтобы сразу найти блоки, имеющие ссылку с определенным классом:

```js
 $('.boxx:has(a.viewsfull)').toggle()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="boxx">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="item stat-panel text-center dub-block">
            <header>
                <h2 class="name-track-short">
                    <div class="play_listfull">
                        <a id="full5640" class="playfull viewsfull" href="#">Crossfaith - Revolution</a>
                    </div>
                </h2> 
            </header>   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

$('div.boxx:has(.viewsfull)').hide();

Comment: Все бы хорошо, но вы забыли, что `viewsfull` - это класс, а значит надо поставить точку перед ним.

Answer (score 1):

Блин, не так быстро умею такие задачки решать)

Но вот чистый js, например.
Или [codepen](http://codepen.io/VostokSisters/pen/dNKMay?editors=1010).

```js
var
  listOfBoxx = document.querySelectorAll(".boxx"),
  listOfATagsFromBoxx = document.querySelectorAll(".boxx * [id^='full']");
 

for (var i = 0; i < listOfATagsFromBoxx.length; i++)
  if (~listOfATagsFromBoxx[i].className.indexOf('viewsfull'))
    listOfBoxx[i].style.display = 'none';
```

```html
<div class="boxx">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="item stat-panel text-center dub-block">
      <header>
        <h2 class="name-track-short">
                    <div class="play_listfull">
                        <a id="full5640" class="playfull viewsfull" href="#">У меня есть класс viewsfull, я не покажусь.</a>
                    </div>
                </h2> 
      </header>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="boxx">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="item stat-panel text-center dub-block">
      <header>
        <h2 class="name-track-short">
                    <div class="play_listfull">
                        <a id="full3214" class="playfull" href="#">А у меня нет этого класса, я покажусь.</a>
                    </div>
                </h2> 
      </header>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```