# Как запретить работу скрипта?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как по нажатию на `input` запретить или разрешить выполнение скрипта?

```
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="news" name="news" value="1"> 
<label for="news">Скрыть новости</label>

$('.boxx').each(function(){
   if($(this).find('a').hasClass('viewsfull')){
   $(this).hide()
   }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, вы немного не поняли задачу. Код выполняется единожды, а не постоянно. Когда вы скрываете новости, это одно действие, и когда оно завершено, ничего фактически не происходит. Чтобы показать снова новости, вам нужно еще один раз выполнить скрипт, который покажет новости.

Например вы ставите обработчик события на `checkbox` `news`:

```
$('#news').on('change', function(){
...здесь ваш код...
})
```

Этот скрипт будет выполнятся каждый раз, когда вы ставите и убираете галочку в `checkbox`. И после выполнения браузер не будет выполнять никаких скриптов, до тех пор, пока не получит следующее событие.

Писать еще один обработчик события не нужно, нам нужно в этом-же определить, нажата галочка или нет:

```
$('#news').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
         //галочка нажата, скрываем новости
    }else{
         //галочка не нажата, показываем новости 
    }
})
```

Далее мы ставим ваш код:

```
$('#news').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
         //галочка нажата, скрываем новости
         $('.boxx').each(function(){
            if($(this).find('a').hasClass('viewsfull')){
               $(this).hide()
            }
         }) 
    }else{
         //галочка не нажата, показываем новости 
    }
})
```

А если мы нажимаем уже второй раз, `$("this").is(':checked')` будет уже не верно, и там нужно новости показать, возьмем тот-же код, но заменим `hide()` на `show()`

```
$('#news').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
         //галочка нажата, скрываем новости
         $('.boxx').each(function(){
            if($(this).find('a').hasClass('viewsfull')){
               $(this).hide()
            }
         }) 
    }else{
         //галочка не нажата, показываем новости 
         $('.boxx').each(function(){
            if($(this).find('a').hasClass('viewsfull')){
               $(this).show()
            }
         }) 
    }
})
```

Рабочий пример:

```js
$('#news').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    //галочка нажата, скрываем новости
    $('.boxx').each(function() {
      if ($(this).find('a').hasClass('viewsfull')) {
        $(this).hide()
      }
    })
  } else {
    //галочка не нажата, показываем новости 
    $('.boxx').each(function() {
      if ($(this).find('a').hasClass('viewsfull')) {
        $(this).show()
      }
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="news" name="news" value="1">
<label for="news">Скрыть новости</label>
<div class="boxx"><a href="#" class='viewsfull'>Новость</a>
</div>
```

Есть еще одна функция, которая упростит скрипт: `toggle()` Она скрывает объекты, если они видимы и показывает, если они скрыты. Т.е все можно упростить до такого:

```
$('#news').on('change', function(){
         $('.boxx').each(function(){
            if($(this).find('a').hasClass('viewsfull')){
               $(this).toggle()
            }
         }) 
})
```

Pavel Mayorov также указал на то, что проще использовать селектор [:has](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/), чтобы сразу найти блоки, имеющие ссылку с определенным классом:

```
$('#news').on('change', function(){
         $('.boxx:has(a.viewsfull)').toggle()
})
```

Comment: У меня почему-то только с `toggle()` работает, `hide() show()` не работает.

Comment: @steep это потому, что я пропустил ошибку. В конструкции `$(this)` написал `this` в кавычках, что естественно не правильно.

Comment: Небольшое упрощение: `$('.boxx a.viewsfull').toggle()`

Comment: @PavelMayorov Прочитайте [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/623456/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-css-%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83/623464) сначала, чтобы понять, что делает скрипт. Ваше упрощение скрывает ссылку, а не блок.

Comment: Извиняюсь, был невнимательным. Вот так правильнее: `$('.boxx:has(a.viewsfull)').toggle()` (или `.show()`/`.hide()`)

Comment: Или вот так: `$('.boxx').has('a.viewsfull').toggle()`

Comment: @PavelMayorov тогда дополню ответ

Answer (score 0):

Чтоб код выполнялся только при условии, то создайте это условие.
Например вы можете накинуть функцию на событие, например изменение в input.

```js
$('#input').on('input', function() {
  console.log(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input" type="text">
```